# Определить вид устойчивого выражения

Tags: фразеология

Доброго дня,
помогите, пожалуйста, разрешить спор.
Суть спора такова: требуется мнение компетентного человека по вопросу - является ли выражение "упал точно подрубленный" фразеологизмом.
По возможности прошу подкрепить ответ теоретическим обоснованием.
Жду ответа, спасибо.

Comment: @olekula, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Свалился, словно срубленный; отпал, как срезанный; заторопился, как оглашенный; засмеялся, будто умалишённый; упал, как скошенный и т.д. Всё это - сравнения. Ничего устойчивого в них нет. А фразеологизм - крепок, не изменишь его под себя. 
Что говорят словари?

По степени спаянности компонентов фразеологические обороты подразделяются на фразеологические единства, фразеологические сращения и фразеологические сочетания.

Фразеологические сращения – это сочетания слов, общий смысл которых не вытекает из значения входящих в него компонентов (втирать очки, кривая вывезет, бить баклуши, остаться с носом, дать стрекача и другое).

Фразеологические единства – это устойчивые сочетания, переносный смысл которых в какой-то степени мотивирован значением входящих в его состав слов (держать камень за пазухой, тянуть лямку, пускать пыль в глаза, кот наплакал, капля в море и другое).

Фразеологические сочетания – это устойчивые обороты, в которых один из компонентов способен сочетаться только с определёнными словами (трескучий мороз, расквасить нос, одержать победу, вороной конь и так далее). То есть слова “трескучий”, “расквасить”, “одержать”, "вороной" могут сочетаться только с теми словами, с которыми они употребляются в предыдущих примерах фразеологизмов.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте здесь про фразеологизмы:

http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/DicTermin/f.php

Я бы сказал, что это фразеологическое выражение. И запятая там нужна.

Answer (score 0):

http://phraseology.academic.ru/8939/Подрубить_под_корень

Запятая именно в том месте, а то можно и иначе:  Упал точно, подрубленный.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю. Есть фразеологизм "упал как подкошенный", или "рухнул как подкошенный" - это фраз. сочетание, потому что часть его ("как подкошенный") постоянна, а вторую часть можно менять упал - рухнул. А вот "упал, точно подрубленный" - это попытка подменить фразеологизм похожим выражением-сравнением.

Comment: http://www.tutoronline.ru/blog/vidy-frazeologizmov - здесь о типах фразеологизмов - понятно